# How to get the selected checkbox corresponding value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic form with corresponding check box with each row.

```
<?php 
  $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from plan ORDER BY id ASC");
  while($result=mysql_fetch_array($q2))
   {
?>

<tr class="phbg">
 <td width="50%"><?php echo $result['plan_name'];?></td>
 <td width="25%" class="pc"><? echo '$';echo $result['price'];?></td>
 <td width="25%" class="pc"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="  <?php echo $result['id'];?>">
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<? echo $result['price'];?>"></td>
</tr>   
<?php  } ?>

Plan    Price   Choose
PHP       $3     []
.Net      $2     []
C#        $6     []
Java      $2     []
C++       $10    []
ROR       $2     []
```

User can select the multiple options. At last will show the total of the selected plans. For total I redirected that page to total.php page. There I did the total of

the selected plans. On total.php Page I want to get the corresponding Id value or the Plan Name of the selected plans. I just get the id the Last Column but not for

the selected columns. Then after that from total.php page user will fill his/her the details and submit the details along with the selected plans and price. How can I retrieve the id of the selected checkbox Value to show the plans.

Comment: Can we see the data set and DDLs?

Comment: Also, we don't use PHP's mysql_ API any more

Comment: I placed the records directly into the d.b. To get the total amount of the selected check boxes I used below code on total.php                                                       <?php 
$total=0;
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
    $total += $check;
 }
echo '$'; echo $total;
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is wrong:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<? echo $result['price'];?>">
```

As only checked checkboxes get sent to the server, you will not be able to identify the checked box by its ID; if only the third is checked, its key in the array will be `0`. And as you are using the monetary value as its value, you will not be able to identify the checked box by the value as the values of different boxes can be the same.

In short: You will not be able to identify the checked boxes when the form is sent in.

To correct that you need to make *or* the name (key on the server) *or* the value unique so that you can link it to your database.

An easy way to do that for the ID, would be to set the ID in the loop:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[<?php echo $result['id'];?>]" value="<? echo $result['price'];?>">
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ set the key manually
```

Now you can loop over `$_POST['check_list']` and the key in that foreach loop will contain the ID of the item in the database:

```
foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $value) {
  //                             ^^^^ the key
  ...
```

You could of course use the value in the same way.

Comment: Or use the plan name, I guess

Comment: @Strawberry Of course, the key here is to make it unique / identifiable. And the ID would give you a fast database lookup but you could use a slug, the name, etc. as long as it's unique and it is indexed.

Comment: It solved the problem. I got the name of the selected check boxes, but I am trying to separate them delimiter by using implode(), but not getting the relative output.

Comment: @Arvind You should probably ask a new question about that and give the input, the desired output and your code.

Comment: Alright I will ask new question about my current issue.